# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: Error on Jmeter

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB in Jmeter by using JSR223 Sampler. Here is my code:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.bson.Document;


import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;


import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;



import java.util.Arrays;


import com.mongodb.Cursor;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

try {


     MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mymongodb.com:27017");
     MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
     MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getdatabse("mydatbase");  
     MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("employee");

}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

I'm getting error:

ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: Error in Beanshell
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create() is applicable for argument types: (com.mongodb.MongoClientURI) values: [mymongodb.com:27017]
Possible solutions: create(), create(com.mongodb.ConnectionString), create(com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings), create(java.lang.String), create(com.mongodb.ConnectionString, com.mongodb.MongoDriverInformation), create(com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings, com.mongodb.MongoDriverInformation)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1518) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:52) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128) [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at Script11.run(Script11.groovy:44) [script:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) [groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) [java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]

Anyone has any ideas? Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you try creating a `ConnectionString` instead of a `MongoClientURI`, prepend the protocol `mongodb://` and feed that to `MongoClients.create`?

Comment: I did try that: 

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mymongodb.com:27017"); 

getting:

ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: Error in Beanshell
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createCredential(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[C)Lcom/mongodb/MongoCredential;
                at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.createCredentials(ConnectionString.java:718)

Comment: Hmm then try to skip creating the `MongoClientURI` and call the `MongoClients.create` with `"mogodb://mymongodb.com:27017"`

Comment: That’s exactly what I did. Still getting error in my last comment. Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In your previous response it looked like you didn't put the protocol `mongodb://` into the [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

Comment: sorry, I meant I tried MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://mymongodb.com:27017"); and getting MongoCredential.createCredential. I did provide the correct credential.

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies on a [diamond operator](https://medium.com/@aayushid159/diamond-operator-in-java-aad0f8c2726e?source=---------2------------------) which is not supported in Beanshell.

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider choosing `groovy` as the scripting language and your code should start working normally

You might also be interested in [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article